# dropdown box removing styles

Tags: html, css

I am having a bit of trouble with the drop down box. I want my `<a>` elements to be without underline and in the middle of the dropdown-content. You can see my code, I want to remove the underlines from the dropdown-content and I want it to be red when it is hovered. However whenever I try to do that, it gives a false defect.
Here is the code. Test it to see the problem logically!

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
/* Building navigation bar */ 

ul {
    text-align: center;
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding-bottom: 5px;
  background-color: black;
  display: block;
}

li a { 
         text-decoration: none;
   padding: 14px 20px;
   color: white;
  
}

li a:hover { 
             background-color: red;
}

li { 
         display: inline;
}

/* Building about dropdown and the dropdown content */ 

.container { 
           width: 15em;
}

.dropdown { 
        position: relative;
   display: inline-block;
}

.dropdown-content { 
          text-align: center;
          position: absolute;
    display: none;
    background-color: black;
    color: white;
       
} 

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content { 
          display: block;
}


</style>
</head>

<body>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="home.html">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="news.html">News</a></li>
 <div class="dropdown">
    <li><a href="#about.html">About</a></li>
  <div class="dropdown-content"><ul>
       <a style="text-decoration = none;" href="#theMan.html">Hey</a>
    <a href="#hahahaha.html">Hey</a>
    </ul>
      </div>
 </div>
  </ul>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

You have a fair amount of invalid HTML in there. Divs cannot be children of `ul`. You might want to validate your HTML first.

Therefore with a little re-structuring of the HTML to make it valid.

```css
ul {
  text-align: center;
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  padding-bottom: 5px;
  background-color: black;
  display: block;
}
li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  padding: 10px;
  color: white;
}
li a:hover {
  background-color: red;
}
li {
  display: inline-block;
}
/* Building about dropdown and the dropdown content */

.container {
  //width: 15em;

}
.dropdown {
  position: relative;
}
.dropdown-content {
  text-align: center;
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  left: 0;
  display: none;
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
}
.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li><a href="home.html">Home</a>
  </li>
  <li><a href="news.html">News</a>
  </li>
  <li class="dropdown"><a href="#about.html">About</a>
    <ul class="dropdown-content">
      <li><a style="text-decoration = none;" href="#theMan.html">Hey</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#hahahaha.html">Hey</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

[Check My Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/kofimokome/g3b0wL5p/#&togetherjs=nIhUPAswUw)

```css
ul {
    text-align: center;
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding-bottom: 5px;
  background-color: black;
  display: block;
}

li a { 
         text-decoration: none;
   padding: 14px 20px;
   color: white;
  
}

li a:hover { 
             background-color: red;
}

li { 
         display: inline;
}

/* Building about dropdown and the dropdown content */ 

.container { 
           width: 15em;
}

.dropdown { 
        position: relative;
   display: inline-block;
}

.dropdown-content { 
          text-align: center;
          position: absolute;
    display: none;
    background-color: black;
    color: white;
       
} 

 /*added lines*/
.dropdown-content a{
  text-decoration:none;
}
.dropdown-content a:hover{
  color:red;/*font-color will be red*/
}
/*added lines ends here*/



.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content { 
          display: block;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="home.html">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="news.html">News</a></li>
 <div class="dropdown">
    <li><a href="#about.html">About</a></li>
  <div class="dropdown-content"><ul>
       <a href="#theMan.html">Hey</a>
    <a href="#hahahaha.html">Hey</a>
    </ul>
      </div>
 </div>
  </ul>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

1.) You have to put your submenu entries into `li` tags (they are in a `ul` tag!)

2.) The `.dropdown-content` selector/rule has to be changed to `.dropdown-content ul`

3.) quite some other stuff, but that wasn't part of the question.

```css
ul {
  text-align: center;
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding-bottom: 5px;
  background-color: black;
  display: block;
}
li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 14px 20px;
  color: white;
}
li a:hover {
  background-color: red;
}
li {
  display: inline;
}
/* Building about dropdown and the dropdown content */

.container {
  width: 15em;
}
.dropdown {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}
.dropdown-content ul {
  text-align: center;
  position: absolute;
  display: none;
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
  padding: 0;
}
.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content ul {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li><a href="home.html">Home</a>
  </li>
  <li><a href="news.html">News</a>
  </li>
  <div class="dropdown">
    <li><a href="#about.html">About</a>
    </li>
    <div class="dropdown-content">
      <ul>
        <li><a style="text-decoration = none;" href="#theMan.html">Hey</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#hahahaha.html">Hey</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</ul>
```